# How to use ProvidePlugin in webpacker rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

I currently am getting this from trying to use webpack.ProvidePlugin, but doesn't seem to load it right. here's my `environment.js`

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

const { environment } = require("@rails/webpacker");
const vueLoader = require("./loaders/vue");

environment.loaders.append("vue", vueLoader);

environment.plugins.append(
  "Provide", // arbitrary name
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    Vue: "vue",
    _: "lodash"
  })
);

module.exports = environment;
```

and my file `Header.vue`

```
<h1>{{_.capitalize(title)}} </h1>
```

Error:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js:587 [Vue warn]: Property or method "_" is not defined on
 the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is 
reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by 
initializing the property.
```

Comment: Off topic: No need to add vue loader. It comes by default.

looking at my own code, the only difference is the first parameter where you have 'Provide', I have 'ProvidePlugin'. Don't know if that makes a difference though. Secondly, why not just import lodash methods in vue files? Maybe the issue is that when compiling vue files, webpack can't see the global context. Also, by Vue common practices, you should do the capitalization in a computed function

Comment: well the whole point of using `ProvidePlugin` is so that you can provide these values globally, I dont have a problem with importing _ other than its just inconvenient, certain commonly used modules shouldn't have to be all over the repo.

Comment: No, I mean importing only those functions, which you use. Then, when babel implements good tree-shaking algorithms for importing functions, you won't have to rewrite a thing. But that is just a suggestion.

Comment: @Kkulikovskis that i'm doing for other things, just not something like lodash

Answer (score 0):

You can use [vue-lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-lodash) plugin for Vue, which provides lodash in Vue templates and your code will work.

Install it (`npm i vue-lodash`) and configure Vue to use it:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueLodash from 'vue-lodash'

Vue.use(VueLodash, options)
```

And you can use lodash in your Vue templates as you have done in Header.vue :)

Comment: thanks but i don thtink that answer my question why the provider doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This should not be related to webpacker, webpack or the ProvidePlugin.
You can easily check this by accessing _ from your component (i.e. in the created hook).

The issues start when you try to reference the method from your [template](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html):

> Template expressions are sandboxed and only have access to a whitelist of globals such as Math and Date. You should not attempt to access user defined globals in template expressions.

In order to make accessing possible, you could add _ to your data:

```
  data: function () {
    return {
      _
    }
  },
```

However, using _ or $ as prefixes or names is not suggested in Vue because the framework itself reserves a lot of these names ([Source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data)):

> Properties that start with _ or $ will not be proxied on the Vue instance because they may conflict with Vue’s internal properties and API methods. You will have to access them as vm.$data._property.

[Link1](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2098)
[Link2](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2098)

Therefore, you could just use 'lodash' instead of '_'.

```
environment.plugins.append(
  "Provide", // arbitrary name
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    Vue: "vue",
    lodash: "lodash"
  })
)
```

...

```
  data: function () {
    return {
      lodash
    }
  },
```

---

In the wild, ways to actually access lodash as _ globally are:

- Adding lodash to the Vue prototype:

Either

```
Vue.prototype._ = _
```

or

```
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '_', { value: _ })
```

[Source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html)

- Adding it as a plugin as suggested earlier

[Source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html)

Comment: i think you are sidetracking onto a different issue that I did not know even existed. But I think the issue i'm experiencing is a contemporary one of the current version of webpacker. I could be wrong but my hunch is many others who are experiencing are using the latest and greatest webpacker.

Comment: I acknowledge that I wasn't just trying to "fix your problem", I just wanted to not give you a solution making you run from one issue into another. If you could try to access lodash from within your script, not your template as I suggested in line 1 that would be very helpful to make sure there aren't any actual issues with the plugin or your setup. Since _ is not defined on your Vue instance, this error would occur with any Vue setup the way you're setting up your Vue instance. (Regardless of Webpacker or the Plugin)

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, but as the problem suggests, my question was more specific to the ProvidePlugin usage rather than adding in lodash.